# Symfony 4.4 AnnotationDriver

Tags: symfony, annotations

When I use: php bin/console make:entity, I get the following error:

"Doctrine\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver" does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

[Symfony 4.4 support has been dropped](https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle/pull/1098) for the maker bundle.

You need to upgrade your symfony version (it's not that hard from 4.4 to 5.4).

However, there is a temporary fix if you want by modifying your composer.json and downgrade your doctrine/orm to 2.11 until you migrate to symfony 5.4.

Change your composer.json with:

`"doctrine/orm": "2.11.*",`

And also:

```
"conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*",
        "doctrine/orm": "2.12.0"
    },
```

Don't forget to run `composer update`

Comment: You need to remove the tilde from the orm version `"doctrine/orm": "2.11",` otherwise it just updates back to 2.12.  I know the conflict line is supposed to prevent this but it did not for me.  I find it bizarre that a bundle in the Symfony namespace would just arbitrarily stop supporting 4.4.  Too bad the issue you linked did not say why they were doing such an unfriendly thing.  [More info here](https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle/issues/1090).  Using reflection on a third party bundle was probably not as clever as it may have originally seemed.